# htaccess delete spaces on URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess

Hy, I have this rewriteRule to change a `/search?key=ok`
to `/search/ok`
from a search bar

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /search/%1? [R=302,L]
```

But when I search something with spaces like `ok ko`
it's just return `/search/ok`.
What do I have to change to have `/search/ok-ko` ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression pattern `([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)` matches only alphanumeric characters , you can add `\s` to your pattern to match a space character in Querystring

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=([0-9a-zA-Z\s_-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /search/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: still not working :/ It's still deleting special characters

Comment: @alexismch try changing the `%{QUERY_STRING}` pattern to `^(.+)$` .